# Custom Image issue on Page control

Tags: swift, pagecontrol

i'm trying to set custom image on page control dots. I have tried a custom class for this ,

```
class CustomPageControl: UIPageControl {

@IBInspectable var currentPageImage: UIImage?

@IBInspectable var otherPagesImage: UIImage?

override var numberOfPages: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override var currentPage: Int {
    didSet {
        updateDots()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    pageIndicatorTintColor = .clear
    currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .clear
    clipsToBounds = false
}

private func updateDots() {

    for (index, subview) in subviews.enumerated() {
        let imageView: UIImageView
        if let existingImageview = getImageView(forSubview: subview) {
            imageView = existingImageview
        } else {
            imageView = UIImageView(image: otherPagesImage)

            imageView.center = subview.center
            subview.addSubview(imageView)
            subview.clipsToBounds = false
        }
        imageView.image = currentPage == index ? currentPageImage : otherPagesImage
    }
}

private func getImageView(forSubview view: UIView) -> UIImageView? {
    if let imageView = view as? UIImageView {
        return imageView
    } else {
        let view = view.subviews.first { (view) -> Bool in
            return view is UIImageView
            } as? UIImageView

        return view
    }
}
```

}

After running this code i got this result in my VC,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fttfW.jpg)

I want this result from this,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgeJf.png)

Comment: The way you attached the image is not correct. Please check. Also there is a `}` at the end of the program which is not under formatted program.

Comment: Im passing this class to page control and pass images at current time in my vc. @smilyface

Comment: No. I am saying about the question you posted here with text `enter image description here`